# Why does my counter variable not come back to 0 in a multithreaded scenario?

Tags: c#, windows-services, timer, try-catch-finally

I'm building a Windows Service base class to manages the polling off a schedule's table of any pending task and the running them.

The Windows service is using the `System.Timers.Timer` to start the schedule's table polling.

I'm setting the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThread` to 10 before initialising the timer.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);

        this._Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this._Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PollWrapper);
        this._Timer.Interval = 100;
        this._Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The delegate method called by the timer keeps the count of the running threads so that it can be used in the OnStop() method to wait for each thread to complete before disposing the service.

```
    private void PollWrapper(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfRunningThreads++;

        try
        {
            this.Poll(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //some error logging here
        }
        finally
        {
            numberOfRunningThreads--;
        }
    }




    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this._Timer.Enabled = false;

        while (numberOfRunningThreads > 0)
        {
            this.RequestAdditionalTime(1000);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Often, the service would not stop when I try to stop it from the Windows service management console. If I debug it and add a breakpoint to the OnStop() method I can see that it is not because the numberOfRunningThreads is stuck on a number greater than 0 (often much greater than 10!). No tasks are running and it stays on that number forever!

Firstly, I don't understand how that number could ever be greater than 10, despite the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` should limit it to 10?

Secondly, even if I did not set the maximum number of threads, I would expect the finally block of the PollWrapper's to eventually bring the count back to 0. If the counter stays greater than 0, it can be explained only with the finally block not executing, right!? How that is possible?

And lastly, would you suggest a differently way to limit the Poll to a number of possible concurrent running threads to a fixed number (.NET 3.5)?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:**

After reading Yahia's comments on reentrancy and SetMaxThread I have modified the PollWrapper so that it should always limit the max number of spawned running threads. I will still to make sure Poll is reentrant.

```
private void PollWrapper(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                if(this.numberOfRunningThreads < this.numberOfAllowedThreads)
                {
                    this.numberOfRunningThreads++;

                    Thread t = new Thread(
                        () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                this.Poll(sender, e);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            { 
                                //log exception
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.numberOfRunningThreads);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    t.Start();
                }
            }
```

Comment: you have written some code that is absolutely NOT thread-safe... for example all write access to `numberOfRunningThreads` must be guarded against race condition...

Comment: @Yahia that is due to my limited knowledge in multithreading. I think I have fixed that with Interlocked.Increment/Decrement on the numberOfRunningThreads, do you suggest any other NOT thread-safe parts from the code above?

Comment: since I don't know what `this.Poll` does/access and what exactly `this` is it is hard to tell whether the rest of the code is thread-safe...

Comment: other aspects: setting max threads doesn't prevent queing more than 10 `elapsed` events... it just makes sure that only 10 threads will be running in parallel... next point: the `PollWrpper` is not secured against reentry... is the code reentrancy-safe ?

Comment: @Yahia thank you! Re-reading the first paragraph from MSDN on `SetMaxThreads`, it makes a whole new sense! Poll should be re-entrant, but I will dbl-check. Still I want to control how many threads can run at once. I've changed the code, pls see UPDATE in question.

Comment: It is better but still NOT ok since you access (read) and modify `numberOfRunningThreads` in a way that is NOT thread-safe... AND you discard `Elapsed` events if you ever have already 10 running and another one is raised...

Comment: @Yahia sorry but I don't understand. I'm using a `lock(this)` so `if(this.numberOfRunningThreads < this.numberOfAllowedThreads)` and `this.numberOfRunningThreads++;` should be thread safe as this is locked!? In the delegate thread, instead I'm using  `Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.numberOfRunningThreads)` as that will occur out of the scope of the lock. Which part have I got it wrong?

Comment: no - the `lock(this)` doesn't lock any members !

Comment: @Yahia, you've been the more helpful person, despite the help arrived in bits and pieces! ;) I wouldn't mind to award the answer to you if you could formulate your comments into a single answer. Looking at example 2 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx your last comment does not make sense to me. Can you include an explaination to why you say that `lock(this)` doesn't lock any members. Many Thanks.

Comment: as requested see my answer below including the explanation you asked for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request of OP (see comments above) in regards to the updated question/code:

The [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement behaves like a "critical" section i.e. it stops that specific code block from being executed in parallel - the parameter of `lock` is used as the "syncrhonization object" so that any code block surrounded by a `lock` on the same variable wouldn't be executed in parallel on a different thread.

The lock statement doesn't do anything with the variable/its contents - for example it doesn't "freeze" the contents so they can still be change anywhere anytime in any executing code (parallel) as long as that code is not protected by `lock` and the same variable as a parameter.

If you look at the link I provided (your points to an outdated documentation version for VS2003) it says explicitely that lock(this) for example is NOT ok to use - the reason and a best practice is described accordingly...

ALL of the above renders the provided code (updated version) still not thread-safe (although definitively better than the original version).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are situations where a finally block may never run.

- You can turn off your computer before the finally executes.
- The code in the try block might never terminate (e.g. infinite loop).
- `Environment.FailFast` does not run finally blocks.
- A severe error in the runtime might cause the entire process to crash without executing the finally.

In addition the finally block might start running but not complete if it is interrupted, if it throws an exception, or if it goes into an infinite loop.

---

Here though your problem seems to be that you are using multiple threads but not synchronizing access to shared variables:

```
numberOfRunningThreads++;
```

You need to lock on a shared object here.

Comment: OK, I know that! My use case is quite specific and it is not the case of a computer turning off! This is not the answer I'm hoping to get, can you suggest how to rephrase the title?

Comment: @GiuseppeR, based on my guesses of the solution you might rephrase it like "Why does my counter variable not come back to 0 in a multithreaded scenario?".

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you don't lock the access of numberOfRunningThreads.
Multiple threads can modify this as once causing a race condition where numberOfRunningThreads is not incremented or decremented correctly.

You can use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx), [`Interlocked.Decrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y.aspx) instead of `++` and `..`.

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly assumed, since the lock() did not accept an int, that int operations were atomic! :( Do you have any idea why ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads is however allowing the creation of more than 10 threads?

Comment: @GiuseppeR int read and int write is an atomic operation, but i++ is a read operation, a compute operation and a write operation. If i changes during the compute operation things go bananas.